# Ugly XCode Error: It thinks my NSArray is a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray, exc-bad-access

Whenever I call the code below,

```
BOOL currentState = [[allGroupThreeArray objectAtIndex:indexNumber] getState];
```

I get the the console errors below:

*-[UIImageView objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f574d50*

and

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f574d50'*

I have no idea why it says "UIImageView objectAtIndex" because allGroupThreeArray is an NSArray which is defined above the @implementation by the code below

```
static NSArray *selectedGroupThreeArray;
```

selectedGroupThreeArray is an array of instances of my class "ItemInstance" and "getState" is a public method in that class that returns a bool.

I have spent hours on this and have absolutely no idea what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: indexNumber is defined by the code below

```
int indexNumber = itemNumber-300-1;
```

where itemNumber is a parameter that is sent to the method that all of this is occurring in.

Comment: It looks like your code is fine, so I would go with @DrummerB's fix. It's certainly not your code that's causing the problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors like this are usually signs of memory issues. Your array is probably released, but not set to `nil` before you try to call `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I redeclared the array within the method and it now works. Any idea how I can prevent it from being autoreleased?

Comment: Oh, got it. You have to use [Object retain];